# Nexus 5 Stock Recovery Images

Tags: rom-flashing, nexus-5

I have been searching for quite a while and can't find anywhere to download JUST the STOCK google android recoveries for Nexus 5. I'm looking for the LMY47I recovery.img to be specific. I dont see why I have to download the entire zip from google if I only want the recovery.img. Does anyone have a link or somewhere to download these files? If not I think I'm going to host my own as this could be very useful for people in my situation.

Thanks in advance. Sorry if my google skills are -3 but I have seriously been looking for quite a while and haven't found anything so far.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of them being hosted apart from the [Factory Image](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) archives you mentioned.

Have you checked out [Nexus Root Toolkit by WugFresh](http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/) yet?  Much easier than cruising [XDA](http://www.xda-developers.com/) for solutions and downloads.

Comment: I have taken a look on XDA (no luck). I do actually have that installed on my windows machine but unfortunately I'm at work and my laptop is linux based. Ill check to see if theres a port.

Comment: Ahh.  Just did some poking around.  I should give [Nexulockr](https://launchpad.net/nexulockr) a whirl on with my Linux box.